# On the definition of the Christoffel symbols

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have struggled for quite some time with the covariant derivative of vector fields. It seems that my confusion arises as a result of different definitions in various textbooks.

Some authors introduce the covariant derivative, $(\nabla _{\vec{v}} \vec{u})_p$, at a point $p$ as a map from a vector field $\vec{u}$ in the neighbourhood of $p$ and a tangent vector $\vec{v}$ at $p$ that is: linear in $v$; additive in $u$; obeys the product rule; commutes with contractions; and reduces to partials derivatives on scalars. So,

$$
\nabla _{\nu} u^\mu =
\partial_\nu u^\mu + \Gamma^\mu _{\nu\lambda} u^\lambda
$$

where

$$
\nabla _{\vec{e}_\nu} \equiv \nabla _{\nu} \quad \text{and} \quad  
\nabla _{\nu} \vec{e}_\mu \equiv \Gamma^\lambda _{\mu\nu} \vec{e}_\lambda
$$

I also understand that if we demand metric compatibility and insist that the connection is torsion-free then we have done all that is required to uniquely specify a connection called the Levi-Civita Connection. I am comfortable with all of the above - *there is nothing to clarify so far*.

However, I have also come across many other texts that state that $\partial _{\nu} \vec{e}_\mu \equiv \Gamma^\lambda _{\mu\nu} \vec{e}_\lambda$ and it is usually accompanied by an assertion that the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in their lower two indices because partials commute and $\vec{e}_\mu = \partial_\mu$. The symbols are introduced something like this:

$$
\partial _{\nu} \vec{v} =
\partial _{\nu} (v^\mu \vec{e}_\mu) =
\partial _{\nu} (v^\mu) \vec{e}_\mu +  v^\mu \partial _{\nu} ( \vec{e}_\mu) =
(\partial _{\nu} v^\mu +  v^\lambda \Gamma^\mu _{\lambda\nu}) \vec{e}_\mu
$$

In what way is this correct? To my mind, it feels wrong because a tangent vector should be a *[linear derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra))* but $\partial _{\nu} \vec{e}_\mu = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu}$ is clearly not a Liebnizian operator. Is there any sense in which the partial derivative of a basis vector is legitimately a vector? (I am familiar with [Lie brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) but that is different because the second derivatives cancel out). If it's not correct, why do so many texts insist on introducing the symbols in this way?

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristoffelSymboloftheSecondKind.html) seems to suggest that there are two definitions of the Christoffel symbols floating around but I really don't understand in what circumstances it is valid to state that $\partial _{\nu} \vec{e}_\mu \equiv \Gamma^\lambda _{\mu\nu} \vec{e}_\lambda$ is a vector (although the symmetry in $\mu$ and $\nu$ obviously follows if that is true).

> Unfortunately, there are two different definitions of the Christoffel symbol of the second kind.
>   ..
>   The symmetry of definition (6) means that $\Gamma^k _{ij}=\Gamma^k _{ji}$